# Get modified date of file on web site without using the Last-Modified header value

Tags: python, html, bash, shell

I am attempting to write a bash shell script that will evaluate the modified date of a file on a remote web site and download the file if it is more recent than the local copy.  Part of the script is already written.  The part that has been developed uses the header Last-Modified parameter.   I need to have an alternative in case the Last-Modified parameter is not available in the header.  Does anyone know of a way using bash shell scripting or python to get the last modified date of as file on a website without using the Last-Modified parameter in the header?

Thanks.

James

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned here, it's tough to trust the Last-Modified header on when the file was last updated.

If you don't mind downloading the full contents of the file, you could store the md5 hash of the file. If it's different on subsequent calls, you know the contents of the file changed.

From Bash shell, you could do:

```
curl -s www.google.com | md5
```

Using the excellent python [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library:

```
import requests
import hashlib

r = requests.get('http://www.example.com')
hash = hashlib.md5(r.text).hexdigest()
```

Comment: you have a typo in the function name - should be hexdigest()

Comment: Excellent suggestion, explanation, and example!

Answer (score 0):

If you're retrieving data over http, there is no guarantee that what you're requesting corresponds to a physical file or anything else with a concept of a "last modified" date, so within the http protocol there's no way (other than Last-Modified) to know. You will probably want to retrieve the file if you don't have a sufficiently recent local copy - and you will have to decide for your purposes what "sufficiently recent" is.

If you have a user account on the host and can remotely log in via ssh or similar, it may be possible to inspect an actual file for mod date.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you are basically maintaining a cache.  HTTP has more than just the `Last-Modified` header to facilitate caching, but the logic not all that simple.  W3C has a [discussion](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) of how to implement a cache that you may find helpful.

Comment: There are other HTTP headers, like etags, but if you've decided you can't trust the headers the server gives you, you're just plain out of luck.

Comment: Agreed.  Unless you are willing to actually retrieve the document and compare it, the HTTP headers are all you have.  So trust them, and if they're wrong, that's the server's problem.